# How to trigger crossover AND price above security in Pine Editor

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, back-testing

I have been trying to research how I can trigger LONG and EXIT from both crossover and price above security in my backtesting logic without luck and ask now for assistance with my backtesting pine editor code.

I will include some parts of my code so you see what I trying to do.

```
// add trading pair outside chart data
btc_price = security("BINANCE:BTCUSDT", "D", close)

// compute the indicators ( main chart ETH/USDT ) 
smaInput = input(title="SMA", type=input.integer, defval=1)
indicator1 = sma(close,smaInput)

// compute the indicators BTC
btcsmaInput = input(title="SMABTC", type=input.integer, defval=1)
indicatorbtc = sma(btc_price,btcsmaInput)


// plot the indicators
plot(indicator1, title="Indicator1", color=color.red, linewidth=2)
plot(indicatorbtc, title="Indicator1", color=color.blue, linewidth=2)
```

What I trying to achieve in pseudo-code:
Go Long IF close IS ABOVE indicator1(ETH/USDT) and BTC/USDT price IS ABOVE indicatorbtc
Go Exit IF close IS BELOW indicator1(ETH/USDT) or BTC/USDT price close IS BELOW indicatorbtc

Here is my code that I need help with, the code below does not work as I describe it above in the pseudo-code.

```
// Backtesting Logic
EnterLong =  crossover(close,indicator1) and crossover(btc_price, indicatorbtc)//
ExitLong = crossunder(close,indicator1) or crossunder(btc_price, indicatorbtc) //
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`crossover` and `crossunder` will be `true` for one bar only and that is when the crossing action becomes `true`. Your `AND` condition will fail unless both crossovers happen at the same time.

Here is another idea, use actual values of those variables. So, if `btc_price` is greater than `indicatorbtc`, you know that this crossover has already happened. And to trigger your entry function only once, you can use `crossover()` and the value comparison together.

```
EnterLong =  (crossover(close,indicator1) or crossover(btc_price, indicatorbtc)) and ((close > indicator1) and (btc_price > indicatorbtc))
```

So, the first part `(crossover(close,indicator1) or crossover(btc_price, indicatorbtc))` will only be `true` when one of those crossovers happen. Then you can look at the actual values to figure out if the other crossover has happened in the past. That is the `((close > indicator1) and (btc_price > indicatorbtc))` part.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to help me out here Baris. 
This will help me quite much

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Happy coding and come back whenever you have questions.

Comment: One more question. I notice that when I used ((close < indicator1) and (btc_price < indicatorbtc)) it did not follow this rule Exit IF close IS BELOW indicator1(ETH/USDT) or BTC/USDT price close IS BELOW indicatorbtc

Is the solution to use OR instead of AND here on the close to get it as mention above?:
ExitLong =  (crossunder(close,indicator1) or crossunder(btc_price, indicatorbtc)) and ((close < indicator1) or (btc_price < indicatorbtc))

Comment: It should work with the and operator actually. Can you ask a new question? Please add a screenshot where you think it is not working.